# Mule4 VM Connector listener process 1 message at a time

Tags: mule4

Mule Runtime 4.1.6
mule-vm-connector 2.0.0
How can a Mule4 VM Connector listener be configured to consume one message from a persistent queue and not consume a second until the first is successfully processed?  Is there a message acknowledgement capability?
I've tried using numberOfConsumers="1" but messages are still being consumed as soon as they are published.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add attribute `maxConcurrency="1"` to the flow that contains the VM listener.

For more details about maxConcurrency see https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.3/tuning-backpressure-maxconcurrency

Comment: I have a small query on this @aled, Does VM listener remove the messages from the queue when processed?

Comment: Yes, otherwise the same message would be re-read all the time.

Comment: Thanks for this @aled and second is We are using VM connector in our API to use persistent queues. there we noticed that listening to the messages from VM queue, there is no option to acknowledge the message or remove the message from the queue? so is i correct means its deigned in this way?

Comment: I'm sorry, that is a new question. Please feel free to post it.